# AngularJS ng-repeat carousel without jQuery

Tags: javascript, angularjs, carousel, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to show elements on my page using ng-repeat that will behave like carousel - they should contain a photo, short description, and on click each of them should show long description. Additionally, I would like it to be mobile-friendly - so users can swipe elements horizontally.

This is my first question here, I always find the right answers to my problems on stackoverflow but in this case I'm totally lost.

I found couple of modules that would probably serve my needs (e.g. angular-slick), however most of them contain a lot of code and usually jQuery. I have read that, if possible, jQuery should be avoided in angularJS projects.

Is there a simple, 'angular' way of creating that, without using jQuery?

Comment: jQuery should be avoided if attempted to use directly in the projects, but a directive that wraps a jQuery library is completely fine... Would be faster & easier than making that from scratch. Or if you can find a different angular directive that does the same then go for it.. But sounds like angular-slick should be fine?

Comment: Thanks, seems that Kai's advice will work for me - and regarding plugins depending on jQuery - I want to keep my project as light and simple as possible so I would really like to avoid jQuery dependency. Still not sure  why I didn't look at ui-bootstrap in the first place ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try `ui-bootstrap`. It replaces Bootstrap's jQuery-driven components (including a carousel) with purely Angular stuff.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am not sure why I was under impression that ui-bootstrap requires jQuery :| Seems that bootstrap carousel will work for me, and actually using ngTouch I will be able to make it mobile friendly ;)